# Cannot find module 'ionic-angular'.ts when version upgraded to Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this code in Ionic 3. In Ionic 4,

> Cannot find module 'ionic-angular'.ts(2307)

How can I make it work in ionic 4? can find any solutions...

```
  import { Events, Content } from 'ionic-angular';

  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
  this.content.resize();
  this.content.scrollToBottom()
```

Comment: import statement change in ionic 4. please check answer for detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these detailed migration steps in order to upgrade from Ionic 3 to 4: https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration

For this specific error the answer is:

```
import { Events, IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';

@ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;
// resize() is removed in Ionic 4 (not needed)
this.content.scrollToBottom();
```

Answer (score 2):

From ionic 4 you import statement of `ionic-angular` slightly changed. please import like below.

```
import { Events, Content } from '@ionic/angular';
```

**[Here is a Demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Falert%2Falert.component.ts)**

Hope this will help!

Comment: thanks, but 'Content' not exist also there ('Event' does exist)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
npm i ionic-angular
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the command you used to create a project ? if you don't mention --type=angular file, it dont have angular support.

```
ionic start project_name blank --type=angular
```

Comment: yes I did.. i think this is about ionic 4 is different than 3